# gwt login autofill won't work

Tags: gwt, authentication, autocomplete, autofill

I have a gwt application which has login page, inorder to implement the autofill function i following this url: http://borglin.net/gwt-project/?page_id=467
however the username field can autofill but not the password field. i even checked firefox's passwords setting and can see my username/password saved correctly in the firefox, how come the password field won't autofill?

the following is the html code for my login form:

```
<div id="loginDiv" style="display:none">
<form method="post" action="login" id="loginForm">

<table id="loginTable" valign="center">

  <tr>
  <td id="loginLabel">Username:</td>
  <td><input id="loginUsername" name="username" AUTOCOMPLETE="on"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="loginLabel">Password:</td>
  <td><input id="loginPassword" name="passwd" type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE="on"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><button id="loginSubmit" type="submit">Login</button></td>
  <td><input id="loginRememberMe" name="rm" type="checkbox">Remember Me</checkbox></td> 
  </tr>

</table></form>
</div>
```